# TibcojmsConnectionFactory configuration issues

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I am trying to work on a tibco JMS CDC product. I have issues setting up the configuration and could not find a solution to my problem.

```
import com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class TibcoBusConfiguration {
    @Value("${ems.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${ems.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${ems.topic}")
    private String queue;

    @Value("${ems.server}")
    private String server;

    @Value("${ems.user}")
    private String user;

    @Bean(name = "tibjmsConnectionFactory")
    public TibjmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws javax.jms.JMSException {
        final TibjmsConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory();

        factory.setServerUrl(serverURL());
        factory.setUserName(user);
        factory.setUserPassword(password);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(
        @Autowired TibjmsConnectionFactory tibjmsConnectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();

        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(queue);
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    private String serverURL() {
        return "tcp://" + server + ":" + port;
    }



}
```

Unfortunately JmsTemplate only allows jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory, how do I pass in the TibcoConnectionFactory, because casting is not allowed since the classes do not match. Is my understanding of this incorrect?

I have the following JAR's in my maven setup: tibjms.jar jakarta.jms-api-3.0 javax.jms-api-2.0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is tough because the Tibco docs don't show the entire inheritance hierarchy.  If `TibjmsConnectionFactory` doesn't implement `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` they you may be out of luck.

Comment: Boot 3/Spring 6 moved from the javax to the jakarta namespace for JEE support - you either need to find a Tibco jar for JEE 9 or drop back to Boot 2.7/Spring 5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot 3/Spring 6 moved from the `javax` to the `jakarta` namespace for JEE support - you either need to find a Tibco jar for JEE 9 or drop back to Boot 2.7/Spring 5.3.

Comment: Ahh I see. I will try looking for the jar. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Looks like I have to go with Spring 5.3 for now . Could not find a jar for Tibco. :( Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Any update on this? :) we are trying to configure Tibco with Spring Boot 3 and going back to Spring Boot 2.7 is not a valid scenario for us.

Comment: Best to ask a new question or open an issue against Tibco.. It has nothing to do with Spring. The Tibco folks won’t get a notification of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Encountered same issue. tibjms has jakarta compatible library that comes with Tibco EMS 10.2. Unfortunately, this library is not published in public maven repo.
To be able to use this, download the latest Tibco EMS community edition, install in the system and you will be able to see the lib under tibco/ems/10.2/lib folder with name jakarta.jms-tibjms.jar
Upload it to your private nexus repo and thats it. You need corresponding   jakarta.jms-api dependency. This library is available in public maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3 moved to the jakarta namespace. To be compatible with it, you need to use the (jakarta) client libraries from TIBCO EMS 10, those are backwards compatible.